# Occuring Rarely: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

I understand questions similar to this have been asked numerous times and answered numerous times.

I have a weird issue where I can only get this exception to occur occasionally. It is inconsistent with no pattern, and just randomly occurs.

Exception: NullReferenceException was unhandled
Text: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The line where the exception occurs:

```
 var query = conn.Table<Items>();
```

conn refers to SQLiteAsyncConnection("items.db");
Items refer to another class containing the database model.

Where am I going wrong? Why does the code work most of the time, but crashes randomly, occasionally? (I do not change any factors, just repeatedly open the application to run through the code again)

Forgot to mention that I am using the sqlite-net plugin available from NUGET, the git can be found here: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

As requested: The Code for Items (Very Basic)

```
public class Items
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

The code for the full method:

```
    private async void ReadData()
    {
            listdata.Items.Clear();

            var query = conn.Table<Items>(); // Exception occurs here 

            var result = await query.ToListAsync();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                listdata.Items.Add(item.Item);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please show how you are declaring Table<Items>() and what does Items look like.. show more code please

Comment: Can you add code just before this line to check whether `conn` is `null` and throw a meaningfull exception in that case? Then you will know a bit more about *what* is null.

Comment: code mostly crashes due to memory leak,try 'using' statement or close connection after use

Comment: @DJKRAZE added the Items code and full method

Comment: Where do you initialize `conn`?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, at application initialization.        
            conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("items.db");

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque http://pastebin.com/Hy3VFM1u

Comment: Are you using the same connection from multiple threads? It's a likely cause for issues that seem to happen randomly. A connection should only be used by one thread. You should open it when you need it and close it as soon as you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I am using the sqlite-net extension, when I checked it, there does not seem to be an obvious close command. That might be the reason. However, there seem to be no issues during the usage of the application, including refreshing the database multiple times. The issue only occurs during startup.

My solution to this is to catch the exception and re-run the ReadData() method, although this is definitely not best practice.